# Google-Refine/add column from Freebase: constraint does not seem to work

Tags: freebase, openrefine

I've got a column of Towns that I reconciled with Freebase.  Now I want to create a new column from Freebase with the populations. I add the column "Population » number" with the constraint

{"year>":"2006",
 "year<":"2012",
 "sort":"-year",
 "limit":1
}

in order to get the most recent number (see http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/issues/detail?id=92#c5). In place of that, I get 10 numbers as if the constraint was not taken in account. Someone can help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Refine is now called OpenRefine and the issue tracker has moved to Github.

Constraints don't work properly on nested properties.  If you split your operation in two and first add a `Population` column with your constraint and then, working off that new column, add a `number` column, you'll be able to get the data you want.

This is the first bug reported in the new issue tracker (yippee!)
See it for more details: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/631

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer Tom! (by the way, I missed something somewhere, why is it not anymore Google Refine?)

Comment: The project is being transitioned to being run by the community without Google's leadership.  It's still the some core team, but without the Google branding or level of support.